# Bayesian 'post hoc' testing

Tags: r, bayesian, post-hoc

I am exploring the world of Bayesian statistics, and am using the [BayesFactor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesFactor/index.html) package in R.

My data is very basic: I have one column (condition) with multiple conditions, my dependent variable is numeric and ranges from 0 to 10. When I run an ANOVA test using a frequentist approach, I follow up with a post hoc test (e.g., Tukey, Bonferroni) to see the effect of the different conditions. My Bayesian Anova reports a very high K value, yet I am unsure how I can follow up this test. I went through the blog post, [Multiple comparisons with Bayes factors](http://bayesfactor.blogspot.fi/2015/01/multiple-comparisons-with-bayesfactor-1.html), but it did not make me much wiser. Any comments on how to approach this problem? (Preferably using R in combination with the `BayesFactor` package).

Comment: 'How to use Bayes factors for multiple comparisons' strikes me as a meaningful, statistical question. IMO, this should be considered on topic here.

Comment: What you would do to follow it up depends on what questions, exactly, you want to answer (/what you want to find out); it sounds like you're taking a rather frequentist style of Bayesian analysis, though, which I think is not using Bayesian stats to its full advantage

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm encountering the same issue